# I am trying to get Json Object into my mobile app, and parse it to be added in Map

Tags: android, json, android-volley

Here is the Json Object

```
{
"Shops": [
    {
        "shop_id": "916TCR",
        "lat": "10.512573",
        "long": "76.255868",
        "Address": "******"
    },
    {
        "shop_id": "RKTCR",
        "lat": "10.527642",
        "long": "76.214435",
        "Address": "Sanfrncisco,USA"
    },
    {
        "shop_id": "LSTCR",
        "lat": "10.527642",
        "long": "76.214435",
        "Address": "afgfagra"
    },
    {
        "shop_id": "WBSTCR",
        "lat": "10.527642",
        "long": "76.214435",
        "Address": "agkangj"
    },
    {
        "shop_id": "BHTTCR",
        "lat": "10.226967",
        "long": "76.193833",
        "Address": "gjognje"
    },
    {
        "shop_id": "KFCTCR",
        "lat": "10.527642",
        "long": "76.214435",
        "Address": "aijaogv"
    },
    {
        "shop_id": "MCTCR",
        "lat": "10.505201",
        "long": "76.269635",
        "Address": "plmqntonf"
    },
    {
        "shop_id": "BHBTCR",
        "lat": "10.527642",
        "long": "76.214435",
        "Address": "agkbajgoj"
    },
    {
        "shop_id": "DMSTCR",
        "lat": "10.528698",
        "long": "76.201991",
        "Address": "fajbjab"
    },
    {
        "shop_id": "CKGTCR",
        "lat": "10.268945",
        "long": "76.157043",
        "Address": "ajnrgj"
    }
]
}
```

i want to get as Shops[0],Shops[1].....
and thereby getting shop_id,lat,long...

I am doing using Volley Library.

Java Code

```
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;
ArrayList<String> items;
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    ListView listView=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.listv);
    items=new ArrayList<String>();
    adapter=new ArrayAdapter(this, R.layout.item_layout,R.id.txt,items);
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);
}
  String url ="Returns Json file"
  JsonArrayRequest jsonArrayRequest=new JsonArrayRequest(url,new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
         public void onResponse(JSONArray jsonArray){
          for (int i=0;i<jsonArray.length();i++) {
try {
                    JSONObject jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                    items.add(jsonObject.getString("shop_id"));
                    items.add(jsonObject.getString("Address"));
                    items.add(jsonObject.getString("lat"));
                    items.add(jsonObject.getString("long"));
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                }
            }
        },new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError volleyError){
            Log.e("Error", "Unable to parse json array");
        }
    });

    requestQueue.add(jsonArrayRequest);
}
```

`

Comment: So what's your question?

Comment: i want to get as Shops[0],Shops[1]..... and thereby getting shop_id,lat,long...@FireSun

Comment: Please paste your complete code,what does items means?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you're getting is a json object containing an array named "Shops". To get the objects in the Shops array, you first need to convert your response to a JSONObject (I called it responseObject in this example), then get its Shops array (shopsArray), then loop through it to get each object (shopObject) and their names/values:

```
JSONArray shopsArray = responseObject.getJSONArray("Shops");

for (int i = 0, i < shopsArray.length(); i++) {
    JSONObject shopObject = shopsArray.getJSONObject(i);
    String shopId = shopObject.getString("shop_id");
    String latitude = shopObject.getString("lat");
    String longitude = shopObject.getString("long");
    String address = shopObject.getString("Address");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change item's type to List,like this:

```
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;
    ArrayList<JSONObject> items;
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        ListView listView=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.listv);
        items=new ArrayList<JSONObject>();
        adapter=new ArrayAdapter(this, R.layout.item_layout,R.id.txt,items);
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
  String url ="Returns Json file"
  JsonArrayRequest jsonArrayRequest=new JsonArrayRequest(url,new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
         public void onResponse(JSONArray jsonArray){
          for (int i=0;i<jsonArray.length();i++) {
try {
                    JSONObject jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                    items.add(jsonObject);
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                }
            }
        },new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError volleyError){
            Log.e("Error", "Unable to parse json array");
        }
    });

    requestQueue.add(jsonArrayRequest);
}
```

you can get item.get(index) to get nth JSONObject and get its attr by item.get(index).getString(attr name).
And I suggest you use Gson and define a model class,it will be more better.